# Как можно передать анимацию в параметре?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочу сделать так:

```
$('#elem').mymethod({
    anim: 'fadeIn'
});
```

И внутри mymeyhod как-то вызывалось

```
$(this).fadeIn();
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос в том, чтобы вызвать анимацию, переданную параметром, то mymethod должен выглядеть так:

```
if (this[anim]) this[anim]();
```

Answer (score 0):

почитай про создание плагинов http://xdan.ru/Kak-napisat-plagin-na-jQuery.html